# The value for key CFBundleVersion in the Info.plist file must be no longer than 18 characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, cfbundleidentifier

Till now, I was able to upload new build to iTunes without any issue, But suddenly today I want to upload new build to iTunes server and Xcode Loader complaining with CFBundleVersion Identifier issue, which is no where matched in my info.plist

```
 ERROR ITMS-90059: "This bundle Payload/appName.app/Frameworks/SlideMenuControllerSwift.framework is invalid. The value for key CFBundleVersion [$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)] in the Info.plist file must be no longer than 18 characters."
```

[image]

Comment: Check your product name in info.plist in earlier versions and now.